# Spring Boot User, Project, Task, Role realtions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, entity, project-management

I want to build a project management app. I have four basic objects: User, project, task and role.

There are a few predefined admin users. Admins create projects, assign users to the project as normal or and project manager. The product manager can create tasks over these projects and assign a normal user to this task.

My problem is I could not figure out how to implement this structure in spring boot.
How can I wire these relations and how should I call these from API.

ps: this is my first QA in StackOverflow so I am asking it improper way forgive me

Comment: So, let me see if I understood well. You are trying to model a database with those object using Spring Data?

Comment: @DamianLisas Yes, this what i want to do.

Comment: I think you should edit your question describing what you already tried, post some code and ask for a specific problem. That's how StackOverflow works. Currently, your question is too broad. There should be enough tutorials on the web, right?